# How to display three divs in line on a row

Tags: html, css-float, css

Ok, I thought my CSS skills had finally gotten to the point where I wouldn't need to ask these kinds of questions, but...

I've got three child divs within a parent div. I want them all to be displayed on the same line, each taking up 33% of the parents' width. As you can see in my fiddle, that's not what's happening. What am I doing wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9nmCC/

HTML

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="div1" class="child-div">
        <p>Div 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" class="child-div">
        <h4>Div 2</h4>
    </div>

    <div id="div3" class="child-div">
        <h4>Div 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent-div {
    background: #555;
}

#div1 {
    float: left; /* Commenting this out results in another weird result*/
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div2 {
    width:33%;
    padding:10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div3 {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child-div {
     /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Comment: When I look at your fiddle, the three block are inline.Have you tried to resize the window?

Comment: If you want to stop them from wrapping, use `white-space: nowrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're fine. The issue is the default margin applied to the `p` tag and `h4` tag. If you set `margin: 0` (and adjust accordingly) you will see all of the boxes are inline. Also change all of them to `float:left` because `inline-block` provides a spacer between the boxes. Just be aware that when you float elements you need to clear them. You can use a clearfix to do that

```
p{
    margin: 0
}

h4{
    margin:0
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9nmCC/3/)

Comment: clearfix unnecessary ... he just has to move overflow:hidden to the parent container. zeroing out the margins of the contents is wrong, as well, as that's not what is altering their containers' widths.

Comment: you can use `overflow:hidden` if you want, it's all personal preference and accomplishes the same thing. But no, zeroing out the margins is not wrong. That was not an issue of the width but of the height. There is a reason people use resets, to kill all of the default styles applied to elements so that you can keep them consistent across browsers.

Comment: Height has nothing to do with putting the elements side by side ... the OP did not say, "I need all three to have the same height," but "I want them all to be displayed on the same line..." Now, yes, if the OP specified that they wanted all the /contents/ to appear horizontally aligned with each other, this would be a place to start, but it leaves out things such as line-height and font-size, which would also affect that alignment.

Comment: i dont have time to argue, point is nothing in my answer was incorrect, it works as expected. You can make a case for "other ways to do it" but that's irrelevant. Reseting the margins is good practice and something that will benefit trevorDashDash as there was height issues in his original fiddle (doesn't matter that he didn't realize or ask for it).

Comment: Your jsFiddle fails in Firefox. So, yes, it's relevant, as this does not address the problem, cross browser.

Answer (score 0):

hope it will help you

```
   h4 , p{
margin:1em;
}
```

view demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/9nmCC/5/

Comment: Huh, that helps. Not sure why though? Also, you forgot to mention that you also need to add `float: left` to all child divs and remove `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `float: left` instead of `inline:block`.  Otherwise the whitespace in-between your divs will cause spacing issues.

```
#div1 {
float: left; /* Commenting this out results in another weird result*/
width: 33%;
padding: 10px;
background: blue;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div2 {
    width:33%;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    background: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#div3 {
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
    float:left;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nmCC/6/)

Comment: `float` and `display` are two different rules, and for a reason. The former determines how the element behaves in relationship to its fellow elements, and the latter determines its relationship to the flow of the DOM. `float` does not remove it from the flow of the document, whereas `display` can do so.

Comment: Thanks, but this answer still gives the first div a different height than the other two.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the padding because that is added to the width of the box, thus making it more than 33% wide and breaking to the next line.

Also, you need to add `float: left;` to `div2` and `div3`.

No need for `display` and `box-sizing`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can still use `inline-block` with `font-size:0` on the parent element, to remove the gaps caused by this `display` value: Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9nmCC/10/

Comment: The first div still has a different height then the other two.

Comment: @trevorDashDash then use `float:left` with `height:100%`

Answer (score 0):

No the main issue is that you are using widths in percentage like 33%, and padding in px.

try with with 27% for each div and padding 3% also for each div, that way you will get 27%+3%+3% - and the complete div width will be 33%

for example:

```
#div1 {
  width: 27%;
  padding: 3%;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/mL93f/

in case you still need padding in px you will need to insert another div in each one and add padding to it.

Comment: Or.... don't mess with padding at all, since he has elements inside the `.child-div` container in each case ...

Comment: Agreed, but I'm just pointing to the one important thing - never combine width in percentage and padding in pixels on one element

Comment: That I can agree with.

Comment: The divs are not lined up in your fiddle, the first div has a different height than the others and there's a big gap to the right of the three divs.

Answer (score 0):

No, folks, what is really throwing the OP's code off is applying padding, as that alters the width of the objects to which padding is added.

http://jsfiddle.net/dGC8u/1/

If you take the padding off the divs, you can see that everything lines up.

If you want additional spacing around the items inside the floated elements, you will have to give the contents margin, as in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGC8u/2/

Honestly, you should also be putting the majority of your common specs into your class (.child-div) rather than repeating it in each id-spec:

```
#parent-div {
    background: #555;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.child-div {
    float: left; /* Commenting this out results in another weird result*/
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child-div p, .child-div h4 {
    margin:10px;
}

#div1 {
    background: blue;
}

#div2 {
    background: red;
}

#div3 {
    background: green;
}
```

This avoids repetition, keeps things consistent across the class-based structure, and only the items that must be specific to each ID are changed. (http://jsfiddle.net/dGC8u/7/)

Lastly, `overflow:hidden` needs to be on the containing element around your floats, or it doesn't do the trick you're looking for (of containing its child elements).

Comment: Hm, better but what is causing the darkgreen gap between div 2 and 3?

Comment: In what browser? (It looks the same in Firefox and Chrome, for me, and I'm not seeing a gap.)

Comment: That's because the second two boxes are not floating, so they fall to the display rule to layout. My example does not show that, because I applied the float to all three boxes.